# another way of calling javascript Function from href tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, internet-explorer-9

I have this code and its working 100% on Chrome and Firefox but not working on IE 9.

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Revenues', '<?php echo $tracking_event; ?>']);
  });

<a href="javascript;" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'social', 'share_fb']);
               window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
               u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog',
               'width=650,height=450');  return false;" class="os_new_icons_fb">
```

Comment: Might just be a typo in your question. But you are missing the closing </script> tag.

Comment: i know its already exist am sorry

Comment: i think the problem in href="javascript;"

Comment: maybe IE9 not support it

Answer (score 1):

This is untested. But try setting a listener for the link instead of defining the JS within the html. E.g.

```
<script>
   $('.my-class').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'social', 'share_fb']);
      window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 'facebook-share-dialog','width=650,height=450');
   });
</script>
```

And then your html would be.

```
<a href="#" class="my-class">CLICK HERE</a>
```